# Hiding "days", "minutes","hours", "seconds" and the

Tags: jquery, divider, flipclock

I have several Flipclock counters. I am looking for a way to hide "days", "minutes","hours", "seconds" and the divider between them. I know I can hide digits using different "faces".

For example, with [hourly counter](http://flipclockjs.com/faces/hourly-counter) I can hide "days", with [minute counter](http://flipclockjs.com/faces/minute-counter) I can hide "days" and "hours" and with [Daily Counter](http://flipclockjs.com/faces/daily-counter) I can hide "seconds". But if I need, for example, to leave only "minutes" and "hours" and hide "seconds" and "days" or leave only "hours"/"minutes", how can I do it?

Answer (score 12):

Using the Daily Counter as a base, here's a CSS solution that was the quickest to draw up rather than having to get a PhD in building clock faces. You can wrap this up in a custom plugin extension and build your set of parameters (hideSeconds, hideMinutes, etc) to then apply the appropriate CSS.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/y4kuskc4/1/)

```
.flip-clock-divider.days,
.flip-clock-divider.hours,
.clock ul:nth-child(1),
.clock ul:nth-child(2),
.clock ul:nth-child(3)
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: If you the version you use is 0.7.x, use `.flip-clock-wrapper` instead of `.clock`. In case 0.8.x - `.flipclock-wrapper`.

Answer (score 2):

To hide labels:

```
.flip-clock-label{ display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Not sure if this helped the OP, but it helped me! This was the first post that came up when I was trying to find a way to hide the labels. (I also didn't need the "!important" addon, FWIW.)